# Ionic card background color not changing on click event

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Im Using `Ionic3`.I want to change my ion-card background color whenever the click function fires, i have some problem it does not work for me, any help on this would be great.Thank You

Thanks

**html**

```
<ion-card  [color]="buttonColor" (click)="someAction()" tappable>


          <ion-card-content >
           <p class="item-nme">01.Account Creation Success</p>
            <div item-end class="item-mark"><img src="../assets/imgs/checked.png"></div>
          </ion-card-content>

        </ion-card>
```

**.ts**

```
export class WelcomePage {
    private buttonColor: string = "primary";

    someAction() {
        this.buttonColor = "light";
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to use `style` or `class` ion-card doesnt have direct `color` attribute

Comment: im not clear , can you please update an answer

Comment: are you trying to use primary and light attributes? or general color?

Comment: got it, its my mistake . some css are overwrite , now its work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `ngStyle` or `style.background`. `ion-card` doesn't have direct `color` attribute.

```
<ion-card  [ngStyle]="{'background':buttonColor}" (click)="someAction()" tappable>
          <ion-card-content >
           <p class="item-nme">01.Account Creation Success</p>
            <div item-end class="item-mark"><img src="../assets/imgs/checked.png"></div>
          </ion-card-content>

        </ion-card>
```

Using style:

```
<ion-card  [style.background]="buttonColor" (click)="someAction()" tappable>
          <ion-card-content >
           <p class="item-nme">01.Account Creation Success</p>
            <div item-end class="item-mark"><img src="../assets/imgs/checked.png"></div>
          </ion-card-content>

        </ion-card>
```